# How to use TStream to fill a matrix of integers

Tags: delphi, pgm

I'm trying to read a PGM binary file (http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html) to fill a 0-based 2D matrix of integers (16-bit grayscale values).

The file may be 50 megs, so I'm trying to fill a buffer in one call.

I've never done anything with Streams before, but the Google results on Delphi streams going back 20 years and are a cluttered mess in which I couldn't find my way.

I've managed to lock up Delphi (first time in 15 years!) while running some code that uses pointers and buffers (and probably is based on my misunderstanding of an antiquated approach.)

Here's my pseudo code, doing it integer by integer.  Is there a way to do the read and fill of the matrix with a single Stream call? (Assuming the file was created on the same machine, so byte-sex is the same.)

```
    type 
      TMatrix: Array of Array of Integer;

    procedure ReadMatrix( const AFileName: String;
                          const AStartingByte: Integer;         
                          const AMaxRow: Integer;
                          const AMaxCol: Integer;
                          const AMatrix: TMatrix)
    begin
      SetLength(AMatrix, aMaxRow, aMaxCol);
      Open(AFileName);
      Seek(AStartingByte);
      for Row := 0 to aMaxCol do
        for Col := 0 to aMaxCol do
          AMatrix[Row, Col] := ReadWord
    end;
```

And, no, this isn't a homework assignment! :-)

Comment: To your question, you won't be able to fill 2D array of integers with single or double (depending on `Maxval` value) byte pixel intensity values in "one call". But why that intermediate array anyway? Don't you want rather create a `TGraphic` descendant and data store e.g. as a flat byte buffer (and index pixels in scanline kind of way)?

Comment: Why would you need this to be done in one call? That would be possible but not for a 2d dynamic array. You could use a 1d dynamic array and subsequently perform your own indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated, you cannot read 2D dynamic array in a single operation, because its memory is non continuous. But every 1D subarray can be filled.

I also changed array element type to 16-bit. If you really need matrix of `Integer`  (it is 32 bit), then you have to read 16-bit data and assign elements to Integers one-by-one

```
 type 
      TMatrix = Array of Array of Word;  

 procedure ReadMatrix( const AFileName: String;
                          const AStartingByte: Integer;         
                          const AMaxRow: Integer;
                          const AMaxCol: Integer;
                          const AMatrix: TMatrix)
var
  FS: TFileStream;
  Row: Integer;   
begin
   SetLength(AMatrix, aMaxRow, aMaxCol);
   FS := TFileStream.Create(AFileName, fmOpenRead);
   try
      FS.Position := AStartingByte;
      for Row := 0 to aMaxRow - 1 do
         FS.Read(AMatrix[Row, 0], SizeOf(Word) * aMaxCol);
   finally
      FS.Free;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: According to that format specification, pixel intensity values can be also single byte (but that's a mistake of a question as asked).

Comment: @Victoria I hope that author analyzes header (at least he uses `AStartingByte`)

Comment: Thanks MBo for the code and both you and Victoria for the heads up on my usage.  I'm using option -4, so intensities will always be a word.

I REALLY appreciate your postings here.